# How to share data between clients using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a variable for JSON, but I want to make it where everyone that is on that PHP Page will be able to see the same variable contents.

This code should explain more of my situation. 
(I am trying to make it where the page won't reload)

```
    var chats = [];
    var j = jQuery.noConflict();
    j(document).ready(function()
    {
        setInterval(function(i){
            var txt = "";
            var x;
            for (x in chats) {
              txt += chats[x] + " <br />";
            }
            document.getElementById("json").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(chats);
        }, 1000)
    });
    j(document).ready(function() {
        j('#post_button').click(function() {
            $text = $('[name=message]').val();
            $sender = $('#texta').val();
            chatstuff = {
                "sender" : $sender,
                "message" : $text,
            };
            chats.push(chatstuff);
            $('[name=message]').val("");
        });
    });
```

So when it does `document.getElementById("json").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(chats);`, I want everyone to be able to see the same chats content when they are on the same page.

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript runs in the user's browser. Any data in a variable is only visible to that client.

In order to synchronize data between clients, you would need to use something like websockets. Each client (user) would send data to your server and the server would relay all client activity to each client.

A very popular JavaScript websockets library is [socket.io](http://socket.io/). You'll find a plethora of "How to create simple chat in JavaScript with websockets" tutorials if you just start searching for them.

Here's a [socket.io chat demo](http://socket.io/demos/chat/) that's right on there site.

---

***"Why use websockets instead of Ajax?"***

Well, just think about it for a little bit... Ajax is great for clients sending data to the server asynchronously, but what about the server talking to the client?

If user A writes "hello", we can send that to the server using Ajax, but how will users B and C be notified that a new message arrived?

Historically, before websockets, this was done with Ajax "long polling". What that means is each client will make an ajax request to the server every *x* seconds that asks "Hey, any new messages for me to read?"

If you're implementing a realtime chat app, that means *x* is going to be something like a max of `5` seconds otherwise users will be too frustrated with the lag.

Pinging our server every 5 seconds to ask the same question over and over is annoying. And it's quite archaic by today's standards. Maybe there's a better way...

***"OK, so how does websockets make this better?"***

Well websockets allows a connection between the client and server to stay *open*. This means that the server can send data to the client as soon as data arrives, without the client having to ask for it.

This means that we can ditch the polling *and* get data sync'd up even faster! Sweet!

***"OK, that's great, but I can't rely on bleeding edge technologies..."***

Well that's not really a problem either. The reason I recommended a websocket lib (e.g., socket.io) is because the socket.io will make a wide variety of attempts to achieve a socket-like connection in the event that your browser doesn't support actual websockets.

Included in a list of fallback methods is none other than... *drumroll, please*... Ajax long polling.

***"Is there any alternative to socket.io?"***

Yep. Now that you know you're looking for it should be easy to find tons of options out there. [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) is another great lib that i'd definitely check out if socket.io seems too heavy-handed for you.

Comment: thanks for giving me the idea, this will be my secondary if i can't seem to be able to use ajax.

Comment: actually i will try this out, thanks again so much, been searching for a while for ways.

Answer (score 0):

no, you have to use a server for this. send new data from this page to the server and the server will update the page for other viewers. consider reading some tutorials like this http://tutorialzine.com/2010/10/ajax-web-chat-css-jquery/

Comment: Yes, that is using Ajax.

Comment: yes, xmlhttp  is a step in the right direction, but the true interaction you can achieve with something more sophisticated like websockets, as @naomik pointed before. with ajax you can only pull the fresh data every X seconds, in contrary websockets can push data to all users at once.

Comment: @vitr I'm sure that if you'll read naomik's answer, you'll change your mind and your answer as well..ajax long polling is not efficient in many ways.

Comment: no doubt, websockets are better, but this doesn't change the concepts of the server and many clients. the sockets are just another implementation.